# Подпись письма сертификатом.

Tags: php

Здравия.
Мне надо на своем сервере подписывать (не шифровать!) письмо сертификатом.
Скажите, в какую сторону гуглить?

Comment: Возможно, что [Авторизованная отправка почты][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугли pgp mail signing php, ssl mail signing php (эти две для подписи клиентским сертификатом, обычно используется как личная подпись). http://www.dkim.org/ (это подписывает письмо сервером mta в заголовках, как гуглопочта) гарантирует сертификатом сервера, что письмо прошло через MTA и  заголовки From/To (на самом деле там можно указывать какие) и тело не измененные после прохождения MTA